# OCaml User-Defined Type and Function Return Error

Tags: error-handling, ocaml, valueerror

I was writing a function with user-defined types in OCaml when I encountered an error message that I don't understand.

I'm currently using the OCaml interactive toplevel and also Visual Studio Code to write my code. The strange thing is that when I run the code in Visual Studio Code, it compiles fine but encounters the error in the interactive toplevel.

The OCaml code that I am referring to is as follows:

```ocaml
type loc = int;;
type id = string;;

type value =
  | Num of int
  | Bool of bool
  | Unit
  | Record of (id -> loc)
;;

type memory = (loc * value) list;;

exception NotInMemory;;

let rec memory_lookup : (memory * loc) -> value
= fun (mem, l) ->
  match mem with
  | [] -> raise NotInMemory
  | hd :: tl -> (match hd with
                 | (x, a) -> if x = l then a else (memory_lookup (tl, l))
                )
;;
```

The code that I wrote is basically my rudimentary attempt at implementing/emulating looking up memory and returning corresponding values.

Here's an **example input**:

```ocaml
memory1 = [ (1, Num 1) ; (2, Bool true) ; (3, Unit) ];;
```

Here's the **expected output**:

```ocaml
memory_lookup (memory1, 2);;
- : value = Bool true
```

However, here's the **actual output**:

```
Characters: 179-180:
                 | (x, a) -> if x = l then "a" else (memory_lookup (tl, l)))
Error: This expression has type value/1076
       but an expression was expected of type value/1104
```

(Just for clarification: the error is regarding character `a`)

Does anybody know what `type value/1076` and `type value/1104` mean? Also, if there is anything wrong with the code that I wrote, would anybody be kind enough to point it out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error happens in the toplevel when a type is defined multiple times, and some values of the old type are left in scope. A simple example is

```
type t = A
let x = A;;
type t = A
let y = A;;
x = y;;
```

> Error: This expression has type t/1012 but an expression was expected of type
>            t/1009

The numerical part after the type name in `value/1076` is a binding time for the type `value`. This binding time is used as a last resort to differentiate between two different types that happens to have the same name. Thus

> Error: This expression has type value/1076
>          but an expression was expected of type value/1104

means that the value `memory1` was defined with a type `value` defined at time `1076`, whereas the function `memory_lookup` expected values of the type `value` defined at a later date (aka at time `1104`). The binding times are a bit arbitrary , so they may be replaced by simply `value/1` and `value/2` in OCaml 4.08 .